# Able to do su into a newly created account but direct ssh is not working

Tags: linux, ssh, su

I need some guidance here.
I have created a new account on the Linux server and encountered a weird problem. The new account is not able to log in and can't even ssh test@localhost I am able to ssh as root and other accounts. While login as another account, I tried su test and it prompts me a password for the test account and I am able to get in.

```
[admin1@server]$ su test
Password: 
[test@server]$ exit
exit
[admin1@server]$ ssh test@localhost
test@localhost's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.

[admin1@server test]$ pwd
/home/test
[admin1@server test]$ sudo cat .bash_profile 
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin

export PATH
[admin1@server test]$

[admin1@server log]$ sudo cat  messages | grep test
Apr  8 12:31:40 server su: (to test) admin1 on pts/0
Apr  8 12:31:40 server su: (to test) admin1 on pts/0
[admin1@server log]$
[admin1@server etc]$ sudo cat sshd_config 
[admin1@server etc]$
```

BTW admin1@server is working.

Comment: Pls show that user's entry in `/etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` enabled in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Either switch this to `yes` or (better) use RSA keys to login to this system.

Comment: How is `PermitRootLogin` involved here, when the user who can't log in is `test`, and the OP mentions that *"I am able to ssh as root [and other accounts]"*?

Comment: You are right, I must have been sleeping.